# Can we design separate layout folder for Samsung galaxy notes

Tags: android, android-layout

Can we design separate layout folder for Samsung galaxy notes. If yes then what would be the name of that folder is layout-800*1200 will be correct. I had desgined layout for large, normal and extra large but when I run my application on Galaxy Note the screen doen't fit into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use

- Layout-small
- Layout-large
- Layout-xlarge
- Layout-normal.

You can only change your AVD resolution and then Check it.

Comment: CAN YOU HELP ME IN CUSTOMIZING MY DESIGN SCREEN FOR GALAXY NOTE. SO THAT I CAN CHECK IT WHILE DESIGNING ONLY

Comment: I m also using galaxy note . Do One thing make a folder named Layout-large in Layout folder and also drawable-large in res folder in which you can put your necessary code. Then create custom AVD change its resolution to 800X1280 and then check your app.

Comment: Even if you have changed the avd to 800 *1280 its not going to help you much.While i created the emulator i had made it to the above mentioned resolution and platform was 2.2.
At that moment it was taking xmls from layout-large.

To the very same AVD,i changed the version to 4.0 and it started taking from normal layout folder.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation for [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) you can only use layout-small,normal,large, xlarge.